# Python telnetlib not reading everything

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm trying to automate the download of Argos data using Python's telnetlib, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to download *all* of the output.  Part of my problem may be that I don't really understand the seemingly asynchronous nature of the commands.

Here's the code:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host = HOST, timeout = 60)
with open("argos_prv_{0}-1.txt".format(now_str), 'w') as of:
    tn.read_until("Username: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.read_until("/")
    # Here's the command I'm trying to get the results of:
    tn.write("prv,,ds,{0:d},009919,009920\n".format(start_doy))
    # At this point, it's presumably dumped it all
    tn.read_until("ARGOS READY")
    tn.read_until("/")
    # Logging out
    tn.write("lo\n")
    lines = tn.read_all()
    of.write(lines)
    of.flush()
```

The code seems to run just fine, but when I look at the output file, it never has everything in it, cutting out at some random point.  When I type the same commands in a real telnet session, it works just fine.

I get the sense it has something to do with trying to `read_all()` after logging out (`tn.write("lo\n")`), but when I look at the example documentation for telnetlib, it pretty much looks just like this.

Anyway, my question is: can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  I want to grab the results of the `prv,,ds` command, but I'm only getting some of it using this particular code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
# At this point, it's presumably dumped it all
tn.read_until("ARGOS READY")
tn.read_until("/")
```

At a guess, this bit is sucking up the data and doing nothing with it. Think of it like a pair of pipes - you send stuff one way with `write`, and pull stuff back with `read_*`. If you've already sucked the stuff up, it won't still be waiting in the pipe when you do `read_all` later.

EDIT:
OK, you're seeing a different problem. Try this:

```
lines = tn.read_until("ARGOS READY")
lines += tn.read_until("/")
tn.write("lo\n")
# Write out lines to file.
```

Comment: That would make sense if this were synchronous, but if you look at the telnetlib example (http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example) they're doing the same thing (reading the result of the `ls` command after sending `exit`).

Comment: It's not sending exit that's the problem. The key is that that example doesn't call `read_*` before it wants to get the data. So the data is still waiting when it calls `read_all` later. Try wrapping those two lines in `of.write(...)`.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I tried commenting out `tn.read_until("ARGOS READY")` and `tn.read_until("/")` (so the code writes `prv,,ds` then `lo`, then `read_all()`), but it does the same thing: I get some of the `prv` output, but the connection seems to terminate before I get it all.

Comment: There's something about not waiting long enough between the data request command `prv` and the logout command `lo`.  If I comment out the `lo` command, the telnetlib debug output shows that I'm receiving all of the output, but since I'm not logging out, the script blocks at `read_all` until the connection is terminated, at which point I don't have the data at all.  It's like I need to send `prv`, wait 59 seconds, send `lo`, then `read_all()` (except this doesn't work either -- I tried it)

Comment: Thanks.  I had already tried this (and pretty much all combinations including `read_until()` and `read_all()` with writing lines at various points).  When I do just what you suggest, all I get are the `ARGOS READY` and `/` lines in the output.  I get the feeling that `read_until` doesn't actually read everything in between, but only returns the line you're looking for.  The rest is sitting in a buffer, but I think that buffer isn't big enough for me to grab everything with `real_all()`, or it gets truncated when the connection terminates as a result of the `lo` command.

Comment: @cswingle: OK, I'm out of ideas then. I don't have a telnet server handy to test on.

Comment: @Thomas K: Thanks for the suggestions.  I may have to set up my own telnet server just to figure it out.